# Failure to succesfully sync an iPod using Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sync, rhythmbox, ipod

After a day of trying to figure out how to get this sync going I found out a few things:

For some reason there has been a lot of trouble syncing iPods with Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 14.04, lots of people apparently have this problem including me.

The most paramount problem that I had today was that every time I would click on my iPod in Rhythmbox under Devices, Rhythmbox would shut down. It took me a while to figure out that the solution to this problem was a very simple one; turning off the following plug-in: "Portable Players - iPod," after I unmarked this check box I was able to access the files on my iPod... However, I am still not able to actually sync my library with the iPod.

so...

Could somebody please help me come up with a good solution for this problem?

I thank y'all very much in advance!

P.S. I have the iPod classic 160GB version so nuthin' fancy.

Comment: I am having the same problem with no workaround yet, so are other people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/1313430?comments=all

Comment: i used before gtkpod it works fine and easy with me code `sudo apt-get install gtkpod gtkpod-data libgtkpod1`

Answer (score 1):

Run command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgpod4 libusbmuxd2 usbmuxd libimobiledevice4 libplist3
```

If you have Synaptic install, find those libraries so you can have the description of each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue as above after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 and attempting to play selections from iPod Nano. Gave up on Rhythmbox and installed Banshee.

```
sudo apt-get install banshee
```